# Sliding 3 divs at a time in a horizontal slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow, slide

I am building a slideshow which shows 3 horizontal divs and 3 links at the bottom.
The links need to slide 3 divs at a time and replace it with the next 3 divs (exactly 3 each click)
here is what I built so far:
http://tipoos.com/buzz

I was wondering if I need to do it in a UL list or just using floating divs. finally decided to use divs.

does anyone know how could I accomplish this?
I would also like it to slide the 3 divs automatically every 5  seconds or so..

will appreciate any help
Thanks, Gil

Answer (score 1):

If a plugin is suitable, then I have previously used: http://gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ which does what you want

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following modification of your page:

http://jsfiddle.net/snies/B4FB5/35/

The main idea is that you need 6 images to be able to scroll 3 in and 3 out.
They live in 1 containig "slider" div, that gets moved. It has to be wide enough for the 6 images. The whole setup is contained by a "slider_window" div only wide enough for 3 images.
This one has the css property "overflow" set to "hidden".

Imagine a cardboard window and a slip of paper with pictures, now you move the slip of paper along the window.

For ease of use and the animation i use jQuery ( http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ).

As soon as the animation is finished, you would switch the images and move the whole div back into position. If you preload the images that switch is fast enough that the user can't see it. Alternatively you could remove images on one side and add new ones on the other sid. In the demo i just move it back into position after 5 seconds.

Comment: Awesome!
is it also possible to loop back smoothly because right now it jumps back to the initial position very fast and doesn't look good. maybe slide back smoothly as it slides normally.

also how do I activate the 3 buttons at the bottom to also trigger the slider?

Thanks a lot!
Gil

Comment: of course it can slide back slow, just use the animate() function instead of the css() function to set it back.

Comment: to activate the buttons just connect a button of your liking to the animte code in the demo. i would suggest using the jQuery .click() method http://api.jquery.com/click/.  $("#button_id").click( function_to_be_called ) -- BTW if you like the answer, it would be nice if you could accept it